# Sorting Values in a dictionary to retrieve the maximum value for each key

Tags: python-3.x

For example: My dictionary is as follows:

```
dic = {'bob':['0,5,1'], 'annie':['2,4,0'], 'charles':['0,7,0']}
```

I want to be able to:

Firstly: Sort the keys so that they are arranged alphabetically

Secondly: Sort the values for each key so that the max value is selected

What I would expect as my outcome is:

```
annie:4
bob:5
charles:7
```

I have been at this for a very long time and have only been able to print out the whole list which has the greatest sum. For example with my current code I get this:

```
[2, 4, 0]
[2, 4, 0]
[2, 4, 0]
```

This is because the program finds the list with the greatest sum and prints that out for each key in the dictionary. I have used `max(dic.values())` for this.

I would really appreciate your help and most efficient methods. Thank You

Comment: Hussain, you are welcome! Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values should be lists of integers, not lists of strings.

```
In [29]: dic = {'bob':[0,5,1], 'annie':[2,4,0], 'charles':[0,7,0]}

In [30]: for k in sorted(dic.keys()):
    print k, max(dic[k])
   ....:     
annie 4
bob 5
charles 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `OrderedDict` and `sorted` function :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> dic_ = {'bob':['0,5,1'], 'annie':['2,4,0'], 'charles':['0,7,0']}
>>> for i,j in sorted((i,max(j[0].split(','))) for i,j in dic_.items()):
...      d[i]=j
... 
>>> d
OrderedDict([('annie', '4'), ('bob', '5'), ('charles', '7')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why every value is a list of only one element which is a string. Here is a solution, but it would make more sense if the value is a list of elements or a comma separated string.

```
for key in sorted(dic.keys()):
    print(key + ":" + str(max(dic[key][0].split(','))))
```